# Implementing In-App Purchase to Disable Ads

Tags: swift, ios8, in-app-purchase, sprite-kit, iad

Below is the code I'm using to creating ads in my app. I am programming in SpriteKit with Swift, and I am trying to implement an in-app purchase such that iAds are disabled when one pays 99¢. How would I go about this?

Here is my code for producing the ads:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    var bannerView:ADBannerView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //enable banner ads
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.bannerView?.delegate = self
        self.bannerView?.hidden = true
    }
    //if banner ad exists, put it on the screen
    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.bannerView?.hidden = false
    }

    //if tapped banner ad, make it full-screen
    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return willLeave
    }

    //if there is no banner ad, take it away
    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        self.bannerView?.hidden = true
    }
}
```

How would I go about implementing a button that when pressed, charges the user 99¢ and removes all ads?

Comment: sprite-kit and swift are already in the tags list, please do not add tags in the question title (DRY principle)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complicated, I'd suggest you take a look over the resources provided by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/), also there is a great tutorial by [Ray](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) (Objective-C).
In order to create In-App Purchases you also have to configure them in the Provisioning Portal.